# Straight line appearing in seaboard barplot

Tags: bar-chart, seaborn

I have a line appearing on one line of my bar plot

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9sDg.png)

and my code below

`````
sns.barplot(x='Police force sent NRM referral for Crime Recording', y='Total', data=dfForces1)
sns.despine()
plt. xticks(rotation=90)


import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax_data = sns.barplot(x= 'Police force sent NRM referral for Crime Recording', y = 'Total', data=dfForces1) # change as per how you are plotting, just for an example
ax_data.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(40)) # it would have a tick frequency of 40, change 40 to the tick-frequency you want.

ax_data.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())````
`````

Comment: You have several values for "Greater Manchester" in your dataset. The line is the errorbar around the mean of those values. Remove duplicate values in order not to see the errorbar and make the bar height unambiguous.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn’t even noticed that!